# Grails Multiple Datasource

Tags: grails, multiple-databases

What plugin or implementation that I can use for grails 1.3.7 to support multiple datasource?

I've already tried using the Datasources grails plugin 0.5 but it has an issue when the domain has defined unique constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will work on 1.3.7, it worked on 2.5.3, but in DataSource.groovy (that is what it is in 2.5.3), something like

```
dataSource {
    // common settings here
}                     
environments {
  production {
     dataSource {
          url = "jdbc:mysql://liveip.com/liveDb"                    
     }          
     dataSource2 {
         url = "jdbc:mysql://liveip.com/otherLiveDb"
     }
  }
}
```

may work; you may have to do a def dataSource2 to get it work (that is what I had to do in 2.5.3).

Comment: Mutliple datasource is already available in grails core in version 2.0 and higher. But it is not supported in 1.3.7 thats why I'm looking for a plugin or another implementation.